# sqlplus CONNECT command with an '@' symbol in the password

Tags: oraclexe, sqlplus

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle XE database using sqlplus.exe with the following command:

```
CONNECT SYSTEM/password@
```

Yes that's right, the '@' symbol is the last letter of the password, and needs escaping.  :(

Many thanks.

See also [Oracle pl-sql escape character (for a ‘&’)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137354/oracle-pl-sql-escape-character-for-a)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
Connect SYSTEM/"password@"
```

or if you need to specify a TNSName

```
Connect SYSTEM/"password@"@tnsname
```

Comment: I've just tried this with a password without the '@' and it works with the double quotes....  Thumbs up Gauthier and thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Try like this.
Connect SYSTEM/\"password@\"@tnsname

Comment: This has been already answered six years ago and your answer doesn't contribute anything new.

Comment: This new answer added the escaped double quotes and helped me out!

Comment: Helped me out too, oddly under a batch script _sqlplus_ is working with the command `sqlplus myuser/password!@dbhost`, but _impdp_ needs the ! escaping and quotes `impdp USERID=myuser/"password^!"@dbhost`. Go figure?!